# adding the parent row id to SubGrid as jqGrid when creating new row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using a jqGrid as a SubGrid, editing a SubGrid row works just fine.
But when trying to add a SubGrid row, the idDiscount (FK) should be posted with the SubGrid form.
I have tried searching this on the web and found nothing about this subject.

As you can see, in my main grid the Primary Key is `idDiscount`,
While on the SubGrid, the Primary Key is `cdDiscount` and a FK `idDiscount`

Code used (trimmed)

```
jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid({
url: '',
        postData: {
        action: "MainGrid"
        },
        editurl: "default.aspx?action=MainGrid",
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['idDiscount'],
        colModel: [{
        name: 'idDiscount',
                index: 'idDiscount',
                hidden: true,
                soratable: false,
                key: true,
        },
                subGrid: true,
                subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowId) {

                var currentRow = $(gridSelector).jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
                var idDiscount = currentRow.idDiscount;
                var subgridTableId, pagerId;
                subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
                pagerId = "p_" + subgridTableId;
                $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pagerId + "' class='scroll'></div>");
                jQuery("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
        url: '',
                editurl: 'default.aspx?action=SubGrid',
                datatype: 'json',
                postData: {
                action: "SubGrid",
                        idDiscount: rowId
                },
                colNames: ['idDiscount', 'cdDiscount'],
                colModel: [{
                name: 'idDiscount',
                        index: 'idDiscount',
                        hidden: true,
                        editable: true,
                        editoptions: {
                        disabled: false,
                                value: idDiscount,
                        },
                }, {
                name: "cdDiscount",
                        index: "cdDiscount",
                        key: true,
                        editable: true,
                        editrules: {
                        required: true
                        }
                ]
                });
                });
```

my full `subGrudRowExpanded`

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowId) {
                var subgridTableId, pagerId;
                subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
                pagerId = "p_" + subgridTableId;
                $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pagerId + "' class='scroll'></div>");
                jQuery("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
                    url: '',
                    editurl: 'default.aspx?action=SubGrid',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    postData: { action: "SubGrid", idDiscount: rowId },
                    colNames: ['Code', 'Percent', 'Title', 'Uses', 'Used', 'From', 'To', 'CreatedBy', ' '],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: "cdDiscount", index: "cdDiscount", key: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
                        { name: "pcDiscount", index: "pcDiscount", editable: true, editrules: { required: true, number:true } },
                        { name: "txDescription", index: "txDescription", editable: true },
                        { name: "ctUses", width: '60px', classes: 'center', index: "ctUses", editable: false },
                        { name: "ctUsed", width: '60px', classes: 'center', index: "ctUsed", editable: false },
                        { name: "dtValidFr", width: '100px', classes: 'center', index: "dtValidFr", editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { datePick(el); } }, editrules: { required: true }, sorttype: 'date', formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "ShortDate" } },
                        { name: "dtValidTo", width: '100px', classes: 'center', index: "dtValidTo", editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { datePick(el); } }, editrules: { required: true }, sorttype: 'date', formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "ShortDate" } },
                        { name: "idUserCreatedBy", index: "idUserCreatedBy" },
                        {
                            name: 'actions',
                            index: '',
                            width: 80,
                            fixed: true,
                            sortable: false,
                            search: false,
                            resize: false,
                            formatter: 'actions',
                            formatoptions: {
                                keys: true,
                                delOptions: { recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback },
                                editformbutton: true,
                                editOptions: {
                                    recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeEditCallback,
                                    addEditOptions: {
                                        onclickSubmit: function () {
                                            return { idDiscount: rowId };
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    ],

                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    pager: pagerId,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: '100%',
                    autowidth: true,
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        var table = this;
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            styleCheckbox(table);
                            updatePagerIcons(table);
                            enableTooltips(table);
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
                jQuery("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pagerId, jqIcons, jqEditForm, jqNewForm, jqDeleteForm, jqSearchForm, jqViewForm);
            },
```

Comment: The code which you posted don't shows **which editing mode** you use (inline editing, form editing or cell editing). The line with `subGridRowExpanded` callback is also removed. Is it `subGridRowExpanded(subgridId, rowId)`? You use both `idDiscount` (see `editoptions: {value: idDiscount}` ???) and `rowId`. It's strange that you included `'idDiscount'` column in the subgrid. Do you really need it or it's just an attempt to solve your main problem?

Comment: it is form editing. i do use `subGridRowExpanded` as needed. i added `editoptions:{value:idDiscount}` as a try to solve it (from something i found on the web. just to make things clear, EVERYTHING works, the only problem is, when adding a row to the SubGrid, the idDiscount is not getting posted with the value of the parent row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [subgrid as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid_as_grid) feature of jqGrid then you implemented `subGridRowExpanded` callback. The second parameter of the callback is the id of the parent grid. If you use `idPrefix` in the main grid (it's recommended to be sure that you will have no id duplicates) you can use `$.jgrid.stripPref` to cut the id prefix and to get the pure `idDiscount` value.

In case of usage form editing you can use `onclickSubmit` callback to extend the data which will be posted to the server during editing. The exact usage of `onclickSubmit` callback depends on how you use form editing. The code fragment below shows just the main idea what you can do

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
    var mainGridPrefix = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
        pagerId = subgridDivId + "_p",
        $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table><div id='" +
                      pagerId + "'></div>"),
        pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId),
        addEditOptions = {
            onclickSubmit: function () {
                return { idDiscount: pureRowId };
            }
        };

    $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
    $subgrid.jqGrid({
        colModel: [
            { name: "cdDiscount", key: true, editable: true,
                editrules: { required: true } }
        ],
        pager: pagerId,
        ....
    }).jqGrid("navGrid", pagerId, {}, addEditOptions, addEditOptions);
```

The data returned by `onclickSubmit` callback should be object which properties will be combined with the main data posted to the server. Returning `{idDiscount: rowId}` will just add `idDiscount` parameter with the rowid of the row of the parent grid.

Comment: ty for that oleg, but i still cant seem to figure it out.
Could you have a look at my edit and tell me what needs to be changed?
i have tried adding the `addEditOptions` but failed. also, but removing my own `subGridRowExpanded` and applying your's, i get an `Element is not a table` error.

Comment: @Dementic: It's *really important* to know how you use editing. If you use `formatter: 'actions'` with `editformbutton: true` then you should include `onclickSubmit` inside of `formatoptions.editOptions`. By the way, if you use `key: true` property for `idDiscount` then `currentRow = $(gridSelector).jqGrid('getRowData', rowId)` will return always `rowId`

Comment: so `rowId` would be the id of the parent row?

Comment: @Dementic: I'm not sure that I understand your question. The second parameter of `subGridRowExpanded` (`rowId` in your code) is the value of `id` attribute of the row (`<tr>`) of the parent grid. If you use `key: true` property for `idDiscount` column in the main grid then the value `id` attribute of the row (`<tr>`) will be *the same* as in the `idDiscount` column (in hidden `<td>` cell). Typically one don't need to use any hidden column and save *duplicate* information in hidden `<td>` and in `id` of `<tr>`. It's enough to save it in `id` only.

Comment: still cant get the `idDiscount` to be posted with the SubGrid Add method... gonna give up (after 18 hours...) i do not understand what im doing wrong, followed your steps (see edited question) but still nothing. gonna search for another grid.

Comment: @Dementic: Why you use `addEditOptions` inside of `formatoptions.editOptions`? You need just use `editOptions: {recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeEditCallback,onclickSubmit: function () {return { idDiscount: rowId };}}`

Comment: Tried everything and anything, i took `addEditOptions` from your answer, then realized it isn't to supposed to be there (reading the docs), tried the way you said in the comments, still not working.

Comment: btw, as i said before, it is working on an edit form, it does not work on an Add new form.

Comment: @Dementic: Do you mean the usage of "Add" button in the navigation bar of subgrid? In the case you need define the same `onclickSubmit` inside of `jqNewForm`. The code which you posted don't contains definition of `jqNewForm` object. So you define it probably in **outer** context. It's wrong you should define if inside of `subGridRowExpanded`. The object `jqNewForm`should have property (method) `onclickSubmit: function () {return { idDiscount: rowId };}`. As closure `onclickSubmit` callback can access any outer variable like `rowId` of `subGridRowExpanded`.

Comment: YES, finally its working, you were right.
i was using the outer scope variable for the settings, since i want the Grid and SubGrid settings to be the same. but i will move them inline.